# Is there a way to specify how un-hovered points should appear in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I see how to customize the appearance of a hovered point in a Bokeh plot, for example with something like

```
p.add_glyph(ColumnDataSource(source), initial_circle, hover_glyph=hovered_circle, ...)
```

but can't see to find anything about customizing the *un*-hovered points when a point is hovered.

Is there a way to specify how un-hovered points should appear, distinct from their default ("initial") appearance, analogous to `nonselection_glyph` vs. `selection_glyph`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bokeh [GlyphRenderer documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/renderers.html) doesn't specifies anything like this. The easy alternative is to create your own `HoverTool` callback to give the un-hovered circles your desired appearance like in this example (working for Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x = [1, 2], y = [3, 4], color = ['blue', 'blue']))
p = figure(tools = 'hover')
c = p.circle(x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'color', size = 20, source = source)

code = '''  if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 0){ 
                selected_index = cb_data.index.indices[0];

                for (index in source.data['color']){
                    if (index == selected_index)
                        source.data['color'][index] = 'red';
                    else
                        source.data['color'][index] = 'yellow';             
                source.change.emit();
            }
            else{
                for (index in source.data['color'])
                    source.data['color'][index] = 'blue';
            } '''
p.select(HoverTool).callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source), code = code)
show(p)
```

Result;

[image]